# How do I include a tip for transactions using Polkadot.JS/API

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript

I am attempting to add a tip to a transaction in the following manner:

```
const batch = await api.tx.utility.batch([...]);
batch.tip = 1;
```

It appears that `tip` is a read-only property and I'm receiving an error.  How may I add a tip to this transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your batch method has a `signAndSend` function attached to it. `signAndSend` takes in `Partial<SignerOptions>` as a second parameter where you would attach your tip. It would look like the following:

`const batch = await api.tx.utility.batch([...]).signAndSend(from, { tip });`

`SignerOptions` can be found [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-base/src/types/submittable.ts#L13-L20).

The following methods that take in `SignerOptions` can be found [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-base/src/types/submittable.ts#L67-L73) for `SubmittableExtrinsics`

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I got this working